# Java Types Basics

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand a answer given, but I dont understand why the answer is "Hello World", hope for someone to explain.

```
public class TestClass{
  public static int getSwitch(String str){
      return (int) Math.round( Double.parseDouble(str.substring(1, str.length()-1)) );
  }
  public static void main(String args []){
    switch(getSwitch(args[0])){
      case 0 : System.out.print("Hello ");
      case 1 : System.out.print("World"); break;
      default : System.out.print("Good Bye");
    }
  }
}
```

What will be printed by the above code if it is run with command line: `java TestClass --0.50` (There are two minuses before 0.)

Comment: What does the `getSwitch` function return? Also, you forgot to put `break;` after the `case 0:` clause.

Comment: @TheCodingMonk OP didn't write the code, and the `break` was deliberately left out as a exercise to show what a missing break means.

Answer (score 1):

According to [JavaDocs Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)

> parseDouble(String s)
>
> Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.

So change your code:

```
public static int getSwitch(String str){
return (int) Math.round( Double.parseDouble(str.substring(1, str.length()-1)));
  }
```

with:

```
public static long getSwitch(String str){
return Math.round(Double.parseDouble(str));
  }
```

because round(double) return long [JavaDocs Math Round](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

> round(double a)
>
> Returns the closest long to the argument, with ties rounding up.

Then replace main with:

```
  public static void main(String args []){
      switch(getSwitch(args[0])){
      case 0 : System.out.print("Hello");
      break;
      case 1 : System.out.print("World"); 
      break;
      default : System.out.print("Good Bye");
      break;
    }
  }
```

And if you run class with `0` it print `Hello` and with `1` print `World`, default operation prints `Good Bye` in according to [JavaDocs Switch Satement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> The default section handles all values that are not explicitly handled
>   by one of the case sections.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int getSwitch(String str) {        // str = "--0.50"
    String x = str.substring(1, str.length()-1); // x = "-0.5"
    double y = Double.parseDouble(x);            // y = -0.5
    long z = Math.round(y);                      // z = 0   (ties rounding to positive infinity)
    return (int) z;                              // returns 0
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    switch (getSwitch("--0.50")) {
        case 0:  System.out.print("Hello ");       // executed because getSwitch returned 0
        case 1:  System.out.print("World"); break; // executed because case 0 didn't end with a break
        default: System.out.print("Good Bye");     // not executed because case 1 did end with a break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already has the answer as a comment.

> What will be printed by the above code if it is run with command line: `java TestClass --0.50` (There are two minuses before 0.)

That means if you run your code trough command line an pass the said argument it will then be stored in `String[] args` at position 0 because its your only and first argument.

After that your algorithm tests the String and tries to convert it to `double`, which will then be tested in your `switch case`.